# Excel - Countifs based on relation between dates

Tags: excel, date, timestamp, comparison, countif

I have a sheet where I'm counting if a value in a cell is older than today.

This formular that I'm using looks like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(H:H;"Not Started";G:G;">F2")
```

It is clearly not working, and I get an error if I remove the quotation marks ("").
The first condition should be working with the H:H,"Not Started", but the second condition is not. 
In the G:G area is a date where the value has a deadline before an action has to be made, and the F2 is the today function (=TODAY()).

How do I check if the value in G:G is older than F2?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite you formula as below, may help

```
=COUNTIFS(H:H;"Not Started";G:G;">" & F2)
```